# MySQL UPDATE with JOIN and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to run the following query:

```
UPDATE task_schedule
JOIN tasks ON (tasks.taskid=task_schedule.taskid)
SET task_schedule.user_position = @counter := @counter + 1
WHERE tasks.userid_owner = 6
ORDER BY task_schedule.product_position asc, task_schedule.productid asc
```

But getting a **Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY** error.

Anyway I could get around this?

Comment: this looks like an XY question. what were you trying to do in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY` is not allowed with the multi-table syntax on `UPDATE`.  Here is one way to fix the query:

```
UPDATE task_schedule
SET task_schedule.user_position = @counter := @counter + 1
WHERE exists (select 1
              from tasks t
              where t.userid_owner = 6 and
                    t.taskid = task_schedule.taskid
             )
ORDER BY task_schedule.product_position asc, task_schedule.productid asc
```